# Idiomatic way to add multiple copies of an enum to a List

Tags: c#, list, enums

I have a structure that is represented as a `Tuple<Enum,int>`.  I need to convert this to a `List<Enum>`, such that the list should have `int` copies of `Enum`. I obviously could use a `while` loop over `List.Add` to do this, but I'm trying hard to avoid using it as it's something that is not guaranteed to terminate.  I'd like to use   something more idiomatic to C#, mostly for general code cleanliness.

The problem, of course, is that there isn't an obvious way to do this with what I'm looking at right now.  The most hilarious idea I had so far was to spawn `int` number of threads that all added `Enum` to the same list, only to die a second later.  But spawning threads is, unsurprisingly, not at all featherweight as far as code goes and it's even more smelly than using a `while`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Repeat` or `Enumerable.Range` for this task:

```
List<FooEnum> enums = Enumerable.Repeat(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2).ToList();
```

(`FooEnum` is the type of your enum in the tuple)

Comment: Freaking bingo.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks some detail, but maybe this will be helpful:

```
Tuple<Enum, int> x = ...
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, x.Item2).Select(i => x.Item1).ToList();
```